# ClassNotFoundException for javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config even when jstl 1.2 is in the classpath

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I am following a guide found [here](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part2.html) in order to learn Spring MVC.  I am making use of Tomcat 8.0.14.
I run into a ClassNotFoundException for javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.  Obviously, I included jslt 1.2 into my build.gradle file as can be seen below but the error remains:
    apply plugin: "war"

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

configurations {
  provided
}

dependencies {

  provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

  compile 'taglibs:standard:1.1.2'
  compile 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl:1.2'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.1.7'

  testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.1.RELEASE"
  testCompile "junit:junit-dep:4.11"

}

sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided

war {
  baseName = "gs-first"
  version = "0.1.0-DEV"
}
```

The exception appears only when I reach step *2.3. Decouple the view from the controller*, in the fore-mentioned guide--only then do I get the exception, all previous steps worked well.

I suspect there is a misconfiguration w.r.t. jstl jar that is expected from `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView` because the `javax.servlet.jsp.jdtl.core.Config` is in the path.

Here's the full exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
        org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:101)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:146)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `jstl` dependency should have a `provided` scope, so should the `servlet-api`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, I did have it as provided initially, only to change it to compile when I started getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was correct to presume that I make use of the wrong jslt library.  Instead of

> compile 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl:1.2'

I need to make use of

> compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'

I just made the wrong choice in the "cacophony" of options maven gave me :).  Thank you for reading and helping :).